# Waiting for Promise to resolve before moving forward

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am working on text parser. The code is intended to work in a browser. It needs to support an ability to allow user to enter value[s] to be used by the parser while the text is being processed. I found a package `dialig-promise` to be used for this purpose, but things are not working like I want. My goal is for `fillMacro()` is to block until the dialog is closed, but it is not happening.

```
  dataMacro(obj) {
    ...
    fragments.push(myDate);
  },
  fillMacro(obj) {
    console.log(`fillText ${JSON.stringify(obj)}`);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      promptPromise("Please enter value for "+ obj.name, obj.defaultValue || '')
      .then(inp => {
        console.log('entered:', inp);
        resolve(inp);
      }, err => {
        console.log("User Escapes. Use default?")
        resolve(obj.defaultValue || '');
      });
    })
    .then(value => {
      fragments.push(value);          
    });
    console.log('finished processing fillText');
  },
  textMacro(obj) {
    ...
    fragments.push(myText);
  }
```

Please advise.

Comment: Promises don't cause anything to block. They just help with writing non-blocking asynchronous code in a sequential manner.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Please show us the code that calls `fillMacro()` - that's where you will need to wait for the promise before moving forward

Answer (score -1):

It's not working because you are returning a promise from `fillMacro` and the code will note wait for your promise to be fulfiled and istead it will continue with the execution. You have multiple solutions for your problem:

1. Make `fillMacro` a promise:

```
    fillMacro = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // make your computations here
    });
```

and then use it:

```
    fillMacro.then((success) => {
      // this part will execute when the promise has been resolved 
    });
```

2. Use [`async await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
3. You could also use [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_generators) and handle the async part on your own, but I think that this solution is not suitable for your scenario.

Comment: I think #1 can be done even with original code, only instead of variable access it needs to be function call.

Comment: You are right, he will have to remove `then` and use it like so: `fillMacro().then(() => {})`

Comment: I would absolutely recommend to avoid #3 now that we have `async`/`await`.

Comment: Doing ```asyncFunc = async () => {
          let value = await promptPromise("Please enter value for "+ obj.name, obj.defaultValue || '');
          return value;
        };
        asyncFunc()
        .then(value => {
          console.log('finished processing fillText, value:', value);
          fragments.push(value);
        });``` obviously does not help. Essentially, it is the same thing as the original albeit with slightly different syntax.